# Dedicated symbol for [...] in quotations?

Tags: spacing, punctuation, quoting

I would like to use [...] in quotations to indicate a part which was not included. Just entering `[...]` does not render it perfectly in my opinion. Is there a special way of inputing said symbol? Thanks.

Comment: The [`csquotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package provides `\textelp{}` for this.

Comment: what about using `[\dots]`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @Guido `[\dots]` has uneven spacing which is easily spotted if you compare: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{csquotes}\begin{document}[\dots] \textelp{}\end{document}`

Comment: If you don't want to use a package just for this, `[\dots\unkern]` should work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can define your own macro for this:

```
\newcommand{\omissis}{[\dots\unkern]}
```

or use the `\textelp{}` macro from `csquotes`.

Note that `\textelp` is a macro taking an argument, so the `{}` after it is mandatory in order to get [...].

A different possibility is to add the kerning also in front of the dots:

```
\newcommand{\somissis}{[\,\dots]}
```

Here'a a minimal document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes} % necessary only for \textelp

\newcommand{\omissis}{[\dots\unkern]}
\newcommand{\somissis}{[\kern\fontdimen3\font\dots]}

\begin{document}
A \somissis{} B

A \omissis{} B

A \textelp{} B

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The macro `\dots` is defined by LaTeX as

```
% latex.ltx, line 1807:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dots}{%
   \ifmmode\mathellipsis\else\textellipsis\fi}
```

In text mode `\textellipsis` is used, which is

```
% latex.ltx, line 1784:
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textellipsis}{%
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font
   .\kern\fontdimen3\font}
```

Here `\fontdimen3\font` is the stretch component of the normal interword space (why this has been chosen would be matter for a debate). The final kerning is responsible for the uneven space; it's desirable in normal text, but not before the closing bracket, so `\omissis` removes it.

Comment: +1, could you explain where the uneven spacing comes from?