# Ellipsis without brackets -- fine tuning

Tags: spacing, punctuation, quoting

Very much related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102615/12277) and [its answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102629/12277), I would like to ask the following:

If I want to indicate omissions in a quotation not by using `Text [...] more text.` but instead by using `Text ... more text.` only (without brackets), is there anything I should keep in mind? Or is there something like the `\textelp{}` macro from `csquotes` fro bracket-less ellipseis?

So far I used `Text \dots\ more text.` and I thought, it looked fine. Is there anything unfavourable about it, which I missed and overlooked? Kerning, spacing, you have it?

Comment: You might be confusing the reader. [...] is a well-recognized way of saying *I'm skipping some stuff*. Only ellipsis means the original text has ellipsis.

Comment: @percusse : I did spent quite some thought on this matter and deliberately chose `Text ... more text.`

Comment: Yes but do we(the readers) know that you have chosen it so? I don't think so.

Comment: @percusse : I don't get your point. My choosing or not choosing is not part of the question.

Comment: The quotations, especially, scientific quotations should follow strict standards. If you omit the brackets they become the original text and not your own modification. You even have to let the reader know that the italics emphasis etc. has been added afterwards. But here you are modifying a well-established standard of skipping text inside a quotation. The reader should be warned for that if you insist on doing so.

Comment: @percusse : I promise to tell them in the preface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be aware of the spacing issue. I suggest using `\dots` in combination with the package [ellipsis](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ellipsis), because that gives you better control over spacing.

`ellipsis` makes it easy to fine tune spacing, and takes care of several other spacing issues, for example ellipsis in combination with another full stop.

In case you want to fine tune ellipsis, you change the distance between the dots simply by the command:

```
\renewcommand{\ellipsisgap}{0.1em} %  or another value
```

Also, by adding the option `[xspace]`, *i.e.*

```
\usepackage[xspace]{ellipsis}
```

terminating the `\dots` command by `\` is not necessary (but even `xspace` makes errors, as documented in the manual). If you use `ellipsis`, remember to load it *after* `hyperref`.

And MWE (the font is Palantino):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}

\usepackage[xspace]{ellipsis}
\begin{document}

This is a test.

This is a test og \dots and dots.

This is a test og \dots\ and dots.

This is a test og \dots. and dots.

This is a test og \dots\ . and dots.


\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: When using `ellipsis` with the `xspace`-option, the result of `\dots` differs from that of `\dots\ ` and, I guess, the latter should be preferred. So using that option does not seem to make "terminating the `\dots` command by `\ ` ... not necessary." Or did I miss something?

Comment: @ClintEastwood When you re using `\dots` I believe _ellipsis_ balances the space before and after the ellipsis. If you are using `\dos\ `, a normal space is entered. Try using a full stop after the ellipsis, i.e `\dots .` and `\dots\ .` and see the difference.

Comment: @Sveinung : I guess you are right with respect to the full-stop-after-ellipsis-case. Using `\dots .` produces a very nice result. But still, `Text \dots more text.` looks a bit weird, when compared to `Text \dots\ more text.`, don't you think?

Comment: @ClintEastwood May be it depends on the font used, because with MinionPro and Palantino (which I tried) the spacing was OK. Optically, the spacing may look different depending on the characters before and after`. (Do you use `Microtype`?).

Comment: @Sveinung : I tried `Minion Pro` with and without `Microtype`. Always the same result: `aaa \dots bbb` ==> `aaa_...__bbb` (more space before `bbb` than after `aaa`) and `aaa \dots\ bbb` ==> `aaa_..._bbb` (same space).

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on whom you ask, (please, anyone correct me if I'm wrong!) and it will also depend on the context and other punctuation.

If used mid-sentence, I personally would tend to use a bit less to no space, and I'd definitely try to balance the space before and after the ellipsis, so I'd probably use `Text \dots\unkern\ more text.` (1) or `Text\,\dots\unkern\,more text.` (2).

[image: samples]

(With CM, I get unbalanced kerning per default, thus the solution above. For other typefaces there might be no difference between (1) and your example.)

But Robert Bringhurst or the Chicago Manual of Style would probably tell you something different ;)

Comment: I get different results. In my document, your option (2) has the same output as (1), and I obtain output (3) only, when using `Text\,\dots\,more text.` (with a `\,` before **and** after `\dots`)

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, could it be that you're using a typeface other than Computer Modern?

Comment: yes, indeed I do.